# Getting list items in SharePoint Hosted App for Office 365

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, office-365, jquery, sharepoint-hosted-app

I want the code snippet for Getting the list items and Show it in the App page. I'm creating SharePoint hosted app for Office 365. How do i get the list item values?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can retrieve all element from YourList, you have change the name of the list in the var list. i hope this code help you!

```
var appURL = decodeURIComponent(getQueryString("SPAppWebUrl"));
var hostURL = decodeURIComponent(getQueryString("SPHostUrl"));

function getItemList(){
   var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appURL);
    var appCtxSite = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, hostURL);
    var web = appCtxSite.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("YourList");
    ctx.load(list);
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Title' /></IsNotNull></Where></Query></View>");
    var listItemToUpdate = list.getItems(query);
    ctx.load(listItemToUpdate);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
            var listEnumerator = listItemToUpdate.getEnumerator();
            while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                console.log("Item: " + listEnumerator.get_current().get_item("Title"));
            }
        }),
        Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
            alert(arguments[1].get_message());
        })
    );
}
function getQueryString(queryString) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        var query = params[i].split("=");
        var req = query[0];
        var result = query[1];
        if (req == queryString)
            return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't, i'm lvl 1